# Go: How to deal with Memory leaks while returning a CString?

Tags: python, go, memory-leaks, ctypes, cgo

I have the following function signature which then return a JSON string

```
func getData(symbol, day, month, year *C.char) *C.char {
  combine, _ := json.Marshal(combineRecords)
  log.Println(string(combine))
  return C.CString(string(combine))
}
```

The Go code is then being called in Python

```
import ctypes
from time import sleep
library = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./deribit.so')
get_data = library.getData

# Make python convert its values to C representation.
# get_data.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p]
get_data.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

for i in range(1,100):
    j= get_data("BTC".encode("utf-8"), "5".encode("utf-8"), "JAN".encode("utf-8"), "23".encode("utf-8"))
    # j= get_data(b"BTC", b"3", b"JAN", b"23")
    print('prnting in Python')
    # print(j)
    sleep(1)
```

It works fine as expected on the Python side but I fear memory leaks when the function will be called in a loop at the Python end.

How do I deal with memory leaks? should I return `bytes` instead of a `CString` and deal bytes at Python end to avoid memory leaks?  I did find [this](https://fluhus.github.io/snopher/) link to deal with it but somehow I do not know the size of JSON string returned after marshalling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python should look like:

```
import ctypes
from time import sleep
library = ctypes.CDLL('./stackoverflow.so')
get_data = library.GetData
free_me = library.FreeMe
free_me.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)]
get_data.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)

for i in range(1,100):
  j = get_data("", "", "")
  print(ctypes.c_char_p.from_buffer(j).value)
  free_me(j)
  sleep(1)
```

The go should look like:

```
package main
/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"
import (
  "log"
  "unsafe"
)

//export GetData
func GetData(symbol, day, month, year *C.char) *C.char {
  combine := "combine"
  log.Println(string(combine))
  return C.CString(string(combine))
}

//export FreeMe
func FreeMe(data *C.char) {
  C.free(unsafe.Pointer(data))
}

func main() {}
```

And use this command line to generate the shared library:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.10 
go version
go version go1.19.2 linux/amd64
go build -o stackoverflow.so -buildmode=c-shared github.com/sjeandeaux/stackoverflow
python3 stackoverflow.py 
2023/01/03 13:54:14 combine
b'combine'                                                                                                                                  
...
```

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install python -y

COPY stackoverflow.so stackoverflow.so
COPY stackoverflow.py stackoverflow.py

CMD ["python", "stackoverflow.py"]
```

```
docker build --tag stackoverflow .
docker run -ti stackoverflow
2023/01/03 15:04:24 combine
b'combine'
...
```

Comment: It gives error `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_char_p instance instead of bytes`

Comment: BTW, you do not need to create new answers for each change.

Comment: I am using Go 1.19

Comment: It seems `FreeMe` wrong parameters are being sent.

Comment: I am using Go 1.19.

Comment: Python `get_data` returns `bytes` which are you passing in `FreeM` so giving error due to incompatible types.

Comment: I edited the post with go / command lines, versions and fixed types in python

Comment: I am not sure why is it not running, when I run on OSX it gives error `python(62628,0x115d94dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x106660230: pointer being freed was not allocated`

And when I run on Ubuntu Digital OCean it gives error: `printing in Python
combine
________________________________
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
`

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error with ubuntu:18.04. I edited the post with the Dockerfile.
Do you know which version is on digital ocean?

Comment: https://github.com/sjeandeaux/stackoverflow/tree/main/go-how-to-deal-with-memory-leaks-while-returning-a-cstring

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you have to free it by using C.free

https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo

```
// Go string to C string
// The C string is allocated in the C heap using malloc.
// It is the caller's responsibility to arrange for it to be
// freed, such as by calling C.free (be sure to include stdlib.h
// if C.free is needed).
func C.CString(string) *C.char
```

Comment: You do... but you have to be very careful about how you do that, because if the Python side just declares the `restype` of `getData` to be `ctypes.c_char_p`, the Python side is going to copy the data into a new `bytes` object and then *discard* the original pointer, leaving no way to free it.

Comment: Stephane, not sure what do you want to say

Comment: @user2357112 yes so how to deal with it?

Comment: `data := getData(...)` and `defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(data))`

Comment: @Volatil3 You have to call `C.free`, when you don't need the data anymore.

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux thanks for the response, could you please add this in your main answer with explanation that whether this will free the memory within Go program due to `CString`? and when I use `.free` will it erase the content of `data` which I want to use later?

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux I just realized I was not clear, Go program then being called in Python. I just updated the question